# Debugging .NET 6 Kubernetes containers

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, kubernetes, f#, .net-6.0

Has someone experience in debugging .NET 6 F# code running in a service-less deployment/pod inside a kubernetes cluster in AKS with Visual Studio (ideally 2022)?

Bridge to Kubernetes is not available for VS 2022, and the VS2019 (and VS code) seems to require a service and an http access. In my case, I have microservices that only use the internal cluster networking between them with a messaging engine, without associated services.

Logs are helpful, but being able to debug would be great.

Ideas?

P.S.

[This](https://dev.to/stevesims2/step-through-debugging-of-code-running-in-kubernetes-using-vs2019-ssh-attach-46p9) is a way, but it looks way too invasive

Answer (score 1):

My experience with this sort of thing is with Java applications, but I assume it would be similar for this platform. This would typically be done with a "port-forward", described on this page: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/ .

Basically, this will provision a local port on your desktop, such that if you connect to that port on your desktop, it will actually be connecting to a mapped port on the pod in the cluster.

Once the port-forward is working, you can connect to that port from vscode.

In Java, this port would be the "debugger port", sometimes referred to as the JPDA port.

Comment: I had thought of port forwarding, but have no idea of what port should be forwarded.

Comment: Me neither. I don't know how the X# debugger protocol works, but it's pretty likely it will work structurally very similar to how Java works.